# Combine SVN and Git Repositories with all history

Tags: git, svn

I've got an old SVN repo, as well as another new Git Repo. They both for the same client, so now I'm trying to combine them together as one Git Repo, but with all the history of commits. Is there any tools or services can get this done easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do this:
https://help.cloudforge.com/hc/en-us/articles/215242983-Migrate-from-SVN-to-GIT

After that, now my local machine has:

```
* master
remotes/git-svn
remotes/origin/Head
remotes/origin/master
```

I can checkout between these remotes, but how do I merge them into remotes/origin/master?

=========================================================================

I found the solution, after above processes, this is what need to be done:

```
git checkout -b git-sve remotes/git-svn  //create a local branch
git checkout master 
git merge git-svn
git push
```